# I'm trying to deploy my Gatsby Blog on Github pages, but "npm run deploy" returns error

Tags: reactjs, github, npm, github-pages, gatsby

I tried to build and deploy my Gatsby blog on github pages.
I followed Gatsby's docs about deploy: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/deploy-gatsby/

I run the following command:

```
npm run deploy
```

I encountered:

```
Cannot read property 'email' of null
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! gatsby-starter-hello-world@ deploy: `gatsby build && gh-pages -b master -d public`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the gatsby-starter-hello-world@ deploy script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/ChaewonKong/.npm/_logs/2018-09-20T09_34_57_114Z-debug.log
```

This is my gatsby-config.js looks like:

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: `Leon Kong's Blog`
  },
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `src`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/`
      }
    },
    `gatsby-transformer-remark`
  ]
};
```

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "gatsby-starter-hello-world",
  "description": "Gatsby hello world starter",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "develop": "gatsby develop",
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "serve": "gatsby serve",
    "deploy": "gatsby build && gh-pages -b master -d public"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "gatsby": "^2.0.0",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^2.0.1",
    "gatsby-transformer-remark": "^2.1.3",
    "react": "^16.5.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.1"
  },
   "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^2.0.0"
  }
}
```

Plus, I'm trying to make an user/organization site like:
https://username/github.io

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing email is not set in your git config. Try to run `git config user.email` to see if it's there.

You can follow this article on how to add it https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-commit-email-address-in-git/.

Also, here are [docs on how to set a github page](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/#enabling-github-pages-to-publish-your-site-from-master-or-gh-pages).

Comment: OK, that's strange. I tried to comment my email in `.gitconfig` and got the same error message. You can try another option - add user settings into the `deploy` script in `package.json` like this: `"deploy": "gatsby build && gh-pages -b master -d public --user \"Your Name <your@email.com>\"",`